# Why does 'ORDER BY' slow query so much?

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query which takes 4 seconds to return results, however when adding an `ORDER BY` the query then takes approximately 40 seconds to return the results.  Why does the `ORDER BY` have such a dramatic difference in the time?

And if I were to have no ability to change the manner in which the data is stored in the database, would I have any other alternatives other than using an `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: If you don't show the query at a minimum (and hopefully the database schema as well) then any answers are just general guidance or stabs in the dark. Help us to help you ;)

Comment: How many records are we talking about?

Comment: Around 400 records are returned in the results

Comment: If you'd show a query then you would get a specific answer.

Comment: I dont want to disclose the query as the information is sensitive, I just wanted to understand why ORDER BY took so long as a general question.

Comment: There is no generic answer to your question.  It's dependent on the SQL query, on the tables involved, etc.

Comment: There's not one answer, but there are multiple answers as have been provided by helpful members of the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order by must analyze all of fields contained in the order by clause for each row from the original select statement.

For example, if you have a table containing 1 million records, and you wrote something like:

```
select top 100 * from tablea
```

would go really fast because as soon as it returns 100 records, it stops the query execution and shows the results.

Now, if you write:

```
select top 100 * from tablea order by tableaid
```

That must select ALL of the 1 million records from the table [that match the where clause], THEN order all of the 1 million records, and THEN return just the first 100 of them.

Comment: "Order by must analyze ALL of the data" - not if there is an index.

Comment: Right OK, so it first returns ALL the results and THEN orders them, so that's where the slowdown is coming from.

Comment: @DStanley, I'm assuming I should change it to "analyze all of fields contained in the order by clause for each row".

Comment: @ganders - yes that's closer.  Although if there's an index it's looking up those values in the _index_ rather than the _data_ (which is generally faster)

Answer (score 2):

Could be lots of reasons:

1. What type of field are you ordering by?  Ordering by text (or large character) fields can be slow because it has to sort the values
2. Are you using a `TOP n` clause?  If so the original query will be fast because it only has to look at `n` records - but an `ORDER BY` will have to look at ALL records to find the `TOP n` unless there is an index on that field (or fields).
3. If there is not an index on the ordering field it will be slower to order by it.
4. The `ORDER BY` could be changing the overall query plan to something much less efficient.

In general, if you often order by the same fields, add indexes that match those orders.